# How to cast a text column into integer column in MS SQL Express?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I am using Microsoft SQL Express and SQL Server Management Studio.

I am following a tutorial to create a small table from scratch and enter some values as per the below code. The tutorial is teaching how to correctly cast a column if by mistake it is incorrectly declared in the first place.

```
CREATE TABLE transactions(
transaction_date date,
amount integer,
fee text
);

SELECT * FROM transactions;

INSERT INTO transactions (transaction_date, amount, fee) 
VALUES ('2018-09-24', 5454, '30');
```

The 'fee' column wrongly created as text. I am trying to typecast this column into integer while using the below code. But this is giving following error. Any suggestions?

```
SELECT transaction_date, amount + CAST (fee AS integer) AS net_amount 
FROM transactions;

Explicit conversion from data type text to int is not allowed.
```

Comment: Why are you using `text` in the first place? It's been deprecated for 16 years.

Comment: Also if you *are* storing data in a string type data type then you are by definition stating that you don't want to perform aggregation or mathematical operations on said data. You have 2 design flaws here: 1. You're using a data type (`text`) that you should have stopped using 16 years ago. 2. You're storing numerical data that you want to treat like a numerical value in a string type data type. Fix your design, use a numerical data type to start with.

Comment: @Larnu, :) I just started learning SQL. The tutorial says so..guess I have a wrong tutorial then. In any case, assuming it as a string column, any suggestions on how to avoid the error?

Comment: Why do you want to use a string type data type to store a "fee" in the first place? As I said, if you want to perform mathematical operations on a value, then don't store it as a string type value; use `int`, `decimal`, or `numeric` to start with. Fix your design, and the issue does not exist.

Comment: Also, if this tutorial you are following *really* tells you to use `text` to store a "fee" then I suggest you stop following it now; it's absolutely awful advice for so many reasons. Find a far better one. There is only one reason a tutorial should tell you to store a monetary value in a string data type (or worse as `text`); to show how disastrous of an idea it is.

Comment: @Larnu, I understand your advise. The tutorial is teaching if by chance a column is wrongly declared, how to correct using typecasting. I guess in real life there is a good chance the column is not correctly imported are defined and we need to convert it to the appropriate form.

Comment: You should have started off with that; that completely changes the question from "I designed by database incorrectly" to "I don't understand this tutorial, this is what it tells me to do."

Comment: @Larnu, Ok.. agreed. I am learning.

Comment: `cast(cast(fee as varchar(20)) as int)`

Comment: Go find a better tutorial. You should focus on learning to write effective and efficient tsql using a pre-built and well-designed database. Designing databases is a very different skill; you should not be doing both at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you the problem here; you can't explicitly (or implicitly) convert/cast a `text` value to an `int`. `text` has been deprecated for 16 years, so you should **not** be using it. It was replaced by `varchar(MAX)` way back in 2005 (along with `nvarchar(MAX)` for `ntext` and `varbinary(MAX)` for `image`).

Instead, you'll need to convert the value to a `varchar` first, and then an `int`. I also recommend using `TRY_CONVERT` for the latter, as a value like `'3.0'` will fail to convert:

```sql
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(int,CONVERT(varchar(MAX),fee))
FROM dbo.transactions;
```

Of course, what you should really be doing is fixing the table:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.transactions ADD TextFee varchar(MAX) NULL; --To retain any data that couldn't be converted
GO
UPDATE dbo.transactions
SET fee = TRY_CONVERT(int,CONVERT(varchar(MAX),fee)),
    TextFee = fee;
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.transactions ALTER COLUMN fee int;
```

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate for taking time to explain and the guidance.